# Make login redirect to a different Route based on a condition Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-8

I am trying to make the login redirect when loggin in successful not to home when a variable called `estado` = 2 but to the reset password view, not because the login fails but because when the variable `estado` of the user equals 2 that means that it has the default password and I want to make the first time the user logs to change his password because of security reasons. (Default password is the same as the username thats why I plan to make mandatory to change the password the first time you log in).

I'm new in Laravel so not sure where I need to do the changes to manage to do that but I think its in the middleware RedirectIfAuthenticated.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  ...$guards
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;

        foreach ($guards as $guard) {
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

If I didn't make clear with what I need I can explain it better, english is not my main language so sorry for any issues. After I change the password with the forgot me functionality I make the `estado` variable change to 1 and I plan to resue it for this so that in future logs in of the user it can log in like normal and go to home.

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
```

Home is a constant `/home`

You can add if condition on this line:

```
If Auth::user()->estado == 2
return redirect(“your reset password route”);
```

However a better way to approach this is to create a new `middleware` and put this condition in it and protect all the authenticated routes with this middleware.

Comment: I see so what you suggest is have all the routes have a middleware that if estado =2 instead of reaching the route tells me to go to reset password. Instead of customizing the login redirect use a middleware for the redirection.

Comment: yes this is actually necessary .RedirectIfAuthenticated will triger just after you login but the user could just go to any other route (lest's say /profile) and without the middlware nothing will stop him/her from going to /profile.

Comment: so all you authenticated route should redirect to reset password page if  estado == 2